# How to archive a build configuration in Teamcity?

Tags: teamcity

Is there a way to archive or temporarily hide a build configuration in Teamcity? The documentation only mentions pausing here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Configuration

Comment: Pause sounds like it would do what you want. What else do you need?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can [archive a project](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Archiving+Projects), but build configurations can only be paused. However, you might be able to achieve something almost as good:

1. Create a project called 'Archive'.
2. Archive the project (*Actions* -> *Archive project...*)
3. Move the build configuration to the 'Archive' project (*Actions* -> *Move configuration...*)

The build configuration will be removed from the original project, but still retrievable should you want to use it again later.

Comment: Not that easy though: "Build configuration cannot be moved. The following VCS roots won't be available in the selected project"

Comment: I used to to this as described above, but I found that in TeamCity 2022.10.2 I first need to de-archive the target project before moving the build configuration, and archive it again after moving. Archived projects are not being presented in the target project list when trying to move build configurations.

Comment: I agree this is an issue, I opened a Youtrack for it, feel free to upvote https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-85986/Cant-move-build-config-into-Archived-project

Answer (score 2):

Go to the 'Administration' panel, select the project you want to archive and click the 'Actions' menu:

[image]

There is no way to archive a build configuration, so you can create a separate project for that purpose (e.g., 'Archive' or 'Attic') and put such configurations there.

Comment: He specifically mentioned that he wants to archive build configurations, not projects.